# Linux - Change gateway dynamically

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, linux-networking, pfsense

in Linux, how can I change the gateway for a destination network dynamically based on the result of a monitor IP (like ping)?

I would like a behaviour like pfSense has with the gateway groups.

Thanks